# Orientation of sphere magnet inside sphere magnet

Tags: electromagnetism

A sphere magnet inside a sphere magnet, both hollow, which of the two orientations will it prefer?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since polarisation is vertical, inside the outer sphere, the «blue pole» is below the top hemisphere (i.e. on the inside of it). Since the opposite polarity will get attracted to it, this means the inner sphere red pole will also face upward (i.e. left picture), given the inner sphere has a way to rotate freely inside the other one.

I should add that the inner sphere is like an inner extension of the outer one, i.e. they should both have the same pole orientation. You could take a full sphere and remove outer layers and will still find the same polarity, assuming the entire sphere was magnetized at once by the same field.

Comment: "the inner sphere is like an inner extension of the outer one" makes sense. what about this one, why does the inner part of this magnet not act as an extension? https://i.imgur.com/BqNIM7F.jpg

Comment: and this person suggests that the magnets (in his example, the outer sphere is an electromagnet) want to align like in example 2, http://asrjetsjournal.org/index.php/American_Scientific_Journal/article/viewFile/2810/1089
https://i.imgur.com/AJRkNjm.png

Comment: are you sure it would not be like in this two-pole induction motor, example 2 in the image above?
https://engineeringtutorial.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/engineeringtutorial.com_two-pole-brushed-dc-motor-working-animation.gif

Comment: (the outer magnet being the stator and the inner magnet the rotor)