# Stator and rotor, both spherical permanent magnets, what is orientation of rotor?

Tags: electromagnetism

If a two-pole spherical permanent magnet rotor is placed within a two-pole spherical permanent magnet stator, and no external force is applied, how does the rotor orient itself? The stator is static, fixed in place, does not move. Below are two example positions for context.

[image]

To admins: If this question is in any way considered "not well received", feel free to clarify what about the question is out of place in this forum. Thanks.

Comment: Like two bar magnets side by side, they will align so that opposite poles are close together.

Comment: In the image, which of the two examples would that be?

Comment: The right side. Think of slicing it into segments like an orange - then each segment is like a horseshoe magnet and a bar magnet.

Comment: Ok, that is my intuition as well, that it is the right side. This answer here suggested the opposite, the left example, that the magnetic poles on the inside of a sphere are reverse and "the inner sphere is like an inner extension of the outer one, i.e. they should both have the same pole orientation", https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/478326/orientation-of-sphere-magnet-inside-sphere-magnet/478369#478369

What do you think of that?